# Packets generated by C program cannot reach router in GNS3

Tags: c, linux, networking, ospf

I'm using a C program to send OSPF packets over to a router in GNS3. I'm using a socket raw to communicate with the router. The problme I'm having is, even though I can receive the packets generated by the router, the packets my program sends, do not seem to reach the router. I've tried using a tap interface, which made it possible to ping the router but my packets still didn't seem to be received by the router.

I then proceeded to try to create two routers, and compare their packets to mine, and verify whether the one I was generating had something wrong, but I couldn't have two routers using the same tap interface. So I had one connected to the tap interface, and the other to my eth0 interface, and only the packet in the eth0 interface received the packets, the other one did not.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and GNS3 to simulate the routers, which are directly connected to a cloud, on which I configured the tap and eth0 interfaces.

Can someone please help me understand how to set up this ?

Comment: Have you tried editing your routing tables?

Comment: The router is part of my network. I have given its interface an IP from the same network I'm making the call from. It should just behave as if it was connected to my real router.

Comment: Can you send any kind of packet to that router?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case, I tried setting a new router to check whether it would communicate with the tap router, but it didn't happen. When I used the tap interface, and configured a bridge using eth0, I could ping the virtual router, but after setting up a router over eth0, they would not sync.

Comment: I dont see why you need a tap for this

Comment: If it is part of the network like you say

Comment: I understand, but googling this, I read that a tap would be needed, and it did work, at least I got to ping it. Besides that, I don't see why I'd need a tap for this either. I need help understanding how to set this up, so I can ping the router from my host machine.